# About iterator and const problem in C++

Tags: c++

```
class LogManager {
  private:
    mutable mapManagerMutex mapMutex;

    typedef std::map<std::string, LogStorage*> FileNameToStorageClass;
    FileNameToStorageClass  m_mapFileNameToLogStrg;

  public:
    int write( const string& strFileName, char* text ) const;

};

int LogManager::write( const string &strFileName, char* text ) const
{
   mapManagerMutex::scoped_lock lock(mapMutex);
   FileNameToStorageClass::iterator iter;
   iter = m_mapFileNameToLogStrg.find(strFileName);
   if(iter != m_mapFileNameToLogStrg.end())
   {
     // do some thing.
   }
   else
   {
     return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Above code compiles if i don't have const at end of write function. If i add const at end i am getting following error

```
D:/LogManager.cpp:133: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'iter = ((const RtsInfrastructure::RtsCommon::Diagnostics::LogManager*)this)-
cc: C:/QNX650/host/win32/x86/usr/lib/gcc/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0/4.4.2/cc1plus caught signal 1
```

Does any body know why we are seeing this?

Comment: For style, you should put the declaration and initialization of `iter` into one statement. Also, why are you using `string` for the file name, but `char *` for the text?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: that's a sharp observation

Answer (score 7):

Because `m_mapFileNameToLogStrg` is treated as a const member inside the const member function. This is because the type of this pointer is 'LogManager const *'. Then how can the iterator `iter` be non-const?

If `iter` is non-const, it could be used to modify the member `m_mapFileNameToLogStrg` (which is treated as const) thereby violating constness.

So here are a few options:

> a) make the member function non-const (write member function being const??)
>
> b) make the string data member
>   mutable.
>
> c) use const_iterator as
>   suggested by Luca Martini

Answer (score 6):

Use `FileNameToStorageClass::const_iterator` instead of `FileNameToStorageClass::iterator`.

Comment: This does not explain the OP's query on why the error is thrown.

Comment: @Chubsbad See your own answer for detailed motivation

Answer (score 0):

> code compiles if i don't have const at end of write function

That tells you that you're doing some non-const operation on a member, such as calling a non-const function.  Given the only member you're doing anything to is `m_mapFileNameToLogStrg`, check whether its `find()` and `end()` are `const`.  Then, as Luca says, the const version of find() should return a const iterator.  If you (or your company) have implemented these container types themselves, its quite possible that they don't even have proper const iterators, so you should add them.